# Discard text selection of text input in React Native

Tags: react-native

So I don't want to turn off the text selection completely but need to deselect the text when certain event happens. Is it possible on RN'S text input?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a **ref** for your input and use **blur method** , that will deselect the text selection like this

```
const TextInputComp = () => {
const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState('My Text');
 
const inputref = React.useRef();
const deselect = () => {
inputref.current.blur()
};

return (
<SafeAreaView>
  <TextInput
    ref={inputref}
    style={styles.input}
    onChangeText={onChangeText}
    value={text}
  />
  
  <Button title="deselect" onPress={deselect}></Button>
</SafeAreaView>
);
};
```